# Отображение анимированного gif изображения загруженного из сети на Android

Tags: java, android, gif, android-animation

**Дано:**

Ссылка на `*.gif` файл.

**Задача:**

Отобразить его в анимированном виде. Да ещё и кэшировать.

**Попытки решения:**

Нашёл вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736861/3212712) два класса. Первый отвечает за декодирование `gif` файла, второй - наследник `ImageView`, принимающий `InputStream` `gif` файла, декодирующий его с помощью первого класса и отображающий анимированное изображение.

Проблема в том, что в этих-ваших-интернетах я нашёл только как отобразить `gif` файл из ресурсов приложения:

`InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.some_gif)`

Немного подумав получил `InputStream` и из простого файла на диске:

`FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);`

Т.е. можно загрузить файл из сети, положить на диск и оттуда грузить. Но хотелось бы это сделать готовым решением. Например с помощью [`UIL`](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), коий сам грузит и кэширует изображения.

Проблема в том, что `SimpleImageLoadingListener` у `UIL` по окончании загрузки выдаёт объект типа `Bitmap`. Его у меня не вышло преобразовать в `InputStream`. Пробовал вот этот код:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
loadedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
```

Но получившийся `ByteArrayInputStream` переданный в конструктор `GifDecoderView` не приводит к отображению картинки. Методы нужные вызываются, но изображение не появляется. Видать, не подходит `ByteArrayInputStream` вместо `InputStream`.

**Возможное решение:**

Решил это костылём таким: По окончании загрузки изображения получаю `File` картинки из дискового кэша `UIL` и преобразую его в `FileInputStream`:

```
File file = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(imageUri, imageLoader.getDiskCache());
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Так оно работает, но меня сильно смущает то, что в момент окончания загрузки я мало того, что получаю `Bitmap` моей картинки, так она ещё и в `MemoryCache` хранится в этот момент. А я, имея всё это гружу, всё же, картинку с диска.

**Вопрос:**

Можно ли как-то получить `InputStream` из `Bitmap` или есть готовые решения самой задачи в виде библиотек? Я нашёл пару [тык](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView) и [тык](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), но не пробовал их, т.к. интересно представленное решение допилить и оно и так, вроде, нормально работает.

**P.S.**:

Используемое в данный момент решение в моём [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479846/17609), но всё ещё интересно как его можно улучшить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно отобразить гифки легко и просто с помощью предложенной @xkor библиотеки [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://domain.com/awersome.gif");
final SimpleDraweeView draweeView = new SimpleDraweeView(context);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);

draweeView.setLayoutParams(params);
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setUri(uri)
        .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
        .build();
draweeView.setController(controller);
//добавляем в разметку и наслаждаемся)
```

Answer (score 3):

Для отображение анимированного gif изображения нашёл на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736861/3212712) два класса:

**GifDecoder.java**

```
public class GifDecoder
{
    public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;
    public static final int STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR = 1;
    public static final int STATUS_OPEN_ERROR = 2;
    protected static final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 4096;
    private static final String LOG = GifDecoder.class.getSimpleName();
    protected InputStream in;
    protected int status;
    protected int width; // full image width
    protected int height; // full image height
    protected boolean gctFlag; // global color table used
    protected int gctSize; // size of global color table
    protected int loopCount = 1; // iterations; 0 = repeat forever
    protected int[] gct; // global color table
    protected int[] lct; // local color table
    protected int[] act; // active color table
    protected int bgIndex; // background color index
    protected int bgColor; // background color
    protected int lastBgColor; // previous bg color
    protected int pixelAspect; // pixel aspect ratio
    protected boolean lctFlag; // local color table flag
    protected boolean interlace; // interlace flag
    protected int lctSize; // local color table size
    protected int ix, iy, iw, ih; // current image rectangle
    protected int lrx, lry, lrw, lrh;
    protected Bitmap image; // current frame
    protected Bitmap lastBitmap; // previous frame
    protected byte[] block = new byte[256]; // current data block

    protected int blockSize = 0; // block size last graphic control extension info
    protected int dispose = 0; // 0=no action; 1=leave in place; 2=restore to bg; 3=restore to prev
    protected int lastDispose = 0;
    protected boolean transparency = false; // use transparent color
    protected int delay = 0; // delay in milliseconds
    protected int transIndex; // transparent color index
    // LZW decoder working arrays
    protected short[] prefix;
    protected byte[] suffix;
    protected byte[] pixelStack;
    protected byte[] pixels;
    protected Vector<GifFrame> frames; // frames read from current file
    protected int frameCount;

    public int getDelay(int n)
    {
        delay = -1;
        if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount))
        {
            delay = frames.elementAt(n).delay;
        }
        return delay;
    }

    public int getFrameCount()
    {
        return frameCount;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        return getFrame(0);
    }

    public int getLoopCount()
    {
        return loopCount;
    }

    protected void setPixels()
    {

        int[] dest = new int[width * height];

        if (lastDispose > 0)
        {
            if (lastDispose == 3)
            {
                // use image before last
                int n = frameCount - 2;
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    lastBitmap = getFrame(n - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    lastBitmap = null;
                }
            }
            if (lastBitmap != null)
            {
                lastBitmap.getPixels(dest, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                if (lastDispose == 2)
                {
                    // fill last image rect area with background color
                    int c = 0;
                    if (!transparency)
                    {
                        c = lastBgColor;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < lrh; i++)
                    {
                        int n1 = (lry + i) * width + lrx;
                        int n2 = n1 + lrw;
                        for (int k = n1; k < n2; k++)
                        {
                            dest[k] = c;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int pass = 1;
        int inc = 8;
        int iline = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ih; i++)
        {
            int line = i;
            if (interlace)
            {
                if (iline >= ih)
                {
                    pass++;
                    switch (pass)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            iline = 4;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            iline = 2;
                            inc = 4;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            iline = 1;
                            inc = 2;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                line = iline;
                iline += inc;
            }
            line += iy;
            if (line < height)
            {
                int k = line * width;
                int dx = k + ix; // start of line in dest
                int dlim = dx + iw; // end of dest line
                if ((k + width) < dlim)
                {
                    dlim = k + width; // past dest edge
                }
                int sx = i * iw; // start of line in source
                while (dx < dlim)
                {
                    // map color and insert in destination
                    int index = ((int) pixels[sx++]) & 0xff;
                    int c = act[index];
                    if (c != 0)
                    {
                        dest[dx] = c;
                    }
                    dx++;
                }
            }
        }
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    }

    public Bitmap getFrame(int n)
    {
        if (frameCount <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        n = n % frameCount;
        return (/*(GifFrame)*/ frames.elementAt(n)).image;
    }

    public int read(InputStream is)
    {
        init();
        if (is != null)
        {
            in = is;

            readHeader();
            if (!err())
            {
                readContents();
                if (frameCount < 0)
                {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            status = STATUS_OPEN_ERROR;
        }
        try
        {
            if (is != null)
            {
                is.close();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i(LOG, "is = NULL!" + " WTF?!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }

    protected void decodeBitmapData()
    {
        int nullCode = -1;
        int npix = iw * ih;
        int available, clear, code_mask, code_size, end_of_information, in_code, old_code, bits, code, count, i, datum, data_size, first, top, bi, pi;
        if ((pixels == null) || (pixels.length < npix))
        {
            pixels = new byte[npix]; // allocate new pixel array
        }
        if (prefix == null)
        {
            prefix = new short[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        }
        if (suffix == null)
        {
            suffix = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        }
        if (pixelStack == null)
        {
            pixelStack = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE + 1];
        }
        data_size = read();
        clear = 1 << data_size;
        end_of_information = clear + 1;
        available = clear + 2;
        old_code = nullCode;
        code_size = data_size + 1;
        code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
        for (code = 0; code < clear; code++)
        {
            prefix[code] = 0; // XXX ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            suffix[code] = (byte) code;
        }
        datum = bits = count = first = top = pi = bi = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < npix; )
        {
            if (top == 0)
            {
                if (bits < code_size)
                {
                    // Load bytes until there are enough bits for a code.
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        // Read a new data block.
                        count = readBlock();
                        if (count <= 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        bi = 0;
                    }
                    datum += (((int) block[bi]) & 0xff) << bits;
                    bits += 8;
                    bi++;
                    count--;
                    continue;
                }
                code = datum & code_mask;
                datum >>= code_size;
                bits -= code_size;
                if ((code > available) || (code == end_of_information))
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (code == clear)
                {
                    // Reset decoder.
                    code_size = data_size + 1;
                    code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                    available = clear + 2;
                    old_code = nullCode;
                    continue;
                }
                if (old_code == nullCode)
                {
                    pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                    old_code = code;
                    first = code;
                    continue;
                }
                in_code = code;
                if (code == available)
                {
                    pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                    code = old_code;
                }
                while (code > clear)
                {
                    pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                    code = prefix[code];
                }
                first = ((int) suffix[code]) & 0xff;
                if (available >= MAX_STACK_SIZE)
                {
                    break;
                }
                pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                prefix[available] = (short) old_code;
                suffix[available] = (byte) first;
                available++;
                if (((available & code_mask) == 0) && (available < MAX_STACK_SIZE))
                {
                    code_size++;
                    code_mask += available;
                }
                old_code = in_code;
            }
            // Pop a pixel off the pixel stack.
            top--;
            pixels[pi++] = pixelStack[top];
            i++;
        }
        for (i = pi; i < npix; i++)
        {
            pixels[i] = 0; // clear missing pixels
        }
    }

    protected boolean err()
    {
        return status != STATUS_OK;
    }

    protected void init()
    {
        status = STATUS_OK;
        frameCount = 0;
        frames = new Vector<>();
        gct = null;
        lct = null;
    }

    protected int read()
    {
        int curByte = 0;
        try
        {
            curByte = in.read();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        }
        return curByte;
    }

    protected int readBlock()
    {
        blockSize = read();
        int n = 0;
        if (blockSize > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                int count;// = 0;
                while (n < blockSize)
                {
                    count = in.read(block, n, blockSize - n);
                    if (count == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    n += count;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (n < blockSize)
            {
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    protected int[] readColorTable(int ncolors)
    {
        int nbytes = 3 * ncolors;
        int[] tab = null;
        byte[] c = new byte[nbytes];
        int n = 0;
        try
        {
            n = in.read(c);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (n < nbytes)
        {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        }
        else
        {
            tab = new int[256]; // max size to avoid bounds checks
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (i < ncolors)
            {
                int r = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                int g = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                int b = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                tab[i++] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            }
        }
        return tab;
    }

    protected void readContents()
    {
        // read GIF file content blocks
        boolean done = false;
        while (!(done || err()))
        {
            int code = read();
            switch (code)
            {
                case 0x2C: // image separator
                    readBitmap();
                    break;
                case 0x21: // extension
                    code = read();
                    switch (code)
                    {
                        case 0xf9: // graphics control extension
                            readGraphicControlExt();
                            break;
                        case 0xff: // application extension
                            readBlock();
                            String app = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                            {
                                app += (char) block[i];
                            }
                            if (app.equals("NETSCAPE2.0"))
                            {
                                readNetscapeExt();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                skip(); // don't care
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0xfe:// comment extension
                            skip();
                            break;
                        case 0x01:// plain text extension
                            skip();
                            break;
                        default: // uninteresting extension
                            skip();
                    }
                    break;
                case 0x3b: // terminator
                    done = true;
                    break;
                case 0x00: // bad byte, but keep going and see what happens break;
                default:
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void readGraphicControlExt()
    {
        read(); // block size
        int packed = read(); // packed fields
        dispose = (packed & 0x1c) >> 2; // disposal method
        if (dispose == 0)
        {
            dispose = 1; // elect to keep old image if discretionary
        }
        transparency = (packed & 1) != 0;
        delay = readShort() * 10; // delay in milliseconds
        transIndex = read(); // transparent color index
        read(); // block terminator
    }

    protected void readHeader()
    {
        String id = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            id += (char) read();
        }
        if (!id.startsWith("GIF"))
        {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            return;
        }
        readLSD();
        if (gctFlag && !err())
        {
            gct = readColorTable(gctSize);
            bgColor = gct[bgIndex];
        }
    }

    protected void readBitmap()
    {
        ix = readShort(); // (sub)image position & size
        iy = readShort();
        iw = readShort();
        ih = readShort();
        int packed = read();
        lctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 - local color table flag interlace
        lctSize = (int) Math.pow(2, (packed & 0x07) + 1);
        interlace = (packed & 0x40) != 0;
        if (lctFlag)
        {
            lct = readColorTable(lctSize); // read table
            act = lct; // make local table active
        }
        else
        {
            act = gct; // make global table active
            if (bgIndex == transIndex)
            {
                bgColor = 0;
            }
        }
        int save = 0;
        if (transparency)
        {
            save = act[transIndex];
            act[transIndex] = 0; // set transparent color if specified
        }
        if (act == null)
        {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR; // no color table defined
        }
        if (err())
        {
            return;
        }
        decodeBitmapData(); // decode pixel data
        skip();
        if (err())
        {
            return;
        }
        frameCount++;
        // create new image to receive frame data
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        setPixels(); // transfer pixel data to image
        frames.addElement(new GifFrame(image, delay)); // add image to frame
        // list
        if (transparency)
        {
            act[transIndex] = save;
        }
        resetFrame();
    }

    protected void readLSD()
    {
        // logical screen size
        width = readShort();
        height = readShort();
        // packed fields
        int packed = read();
        gctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 : global color table flag
        // 2-4 : color resolution
        // 5 : gct sort flag
        gctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 : gct size
        bgIndex = read(); // background color index
        pixelAspect = read(); // pixel aspect ratio
    }

    protected void readNetscapeExt()
    {
        do
        {
            readBlock();
            if (block[0] == 1)
            {
                // loop count sub-block
                int b1 = ((int) block[1]) & 0xff;
                int b2 = ((int) block[2]) & 0xff;
                loopCount = (b2 << 8) | b1;
            }
        } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }

    protected int readShort()
    {
        // read 16-bit value, LSB first
        return read() | (read() << 8);
    }

    protected void resetFrame()
    {
        lastDispose = dispose;
        lrx = ix;
        lry = iy;
        lrw = iw;
        lrh = ih;
        lastBitmap = image;
        lastBgColor = bgColor;
        dispose = 0;
        transparency = false;
        delay = 0;
        lct = null;
    }

    protected void skip()
    {
        do
        {
            readBlock();
        } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }

    private static class GifFrame
    {
        public Bitmap image;
        public int delay;

        public GifFrame(Bitmap im, int del)
        {
            image = im;
            delay = del;
        }
    }
}
```

**GifDecoderView.java**

```
public class GifDecoderView extends ImageView
{
    public static final String LOG = GifDecoderView.class.getSimpleName();

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private boolean mIsPlayingGif = false;
    private GifDecoder mGifDecoder;
    private Bitmap mTmpBitmap;
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (mTmpBitmap != null && !mTmpBitmap.isRecycled())
            {
                GifDecoderView.this.setImageBitmap(mTmpBitmap);
            }
        }
    };

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public GifDecoderView(Context context, InputStream stream)
    {
        super(context);
        playGif(stream);
    }

    public GifDecoderView(Context context, String url)
    {
        super(context);

        imageLoader = MyUIL.get(context);

        imageLoader.loadImage(url, MyUIL.getSimple(), new SimpleImageLoadingListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage)
            {
                super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                Log.i(LOG, "onLoadingComplete for URI: "+imageUri);

                File file = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(imageUri, imageLoader.getDiskCache());

                try
                {
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                    playGif(in);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void playGif(InputStream stream)
    {
        Log.i(LOG, "playGif");
        mGifDecoder = new GifDecoder();
        mGifDecoder.read(stream);

        mIsPlayingGif = true;

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                final int n = mGifDecoder.getFrameCount();
                final int ntimes = mGifDecoder.getLoopCount();
                int repetitionCounter = 0;
                do
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        mTmpBitmap = mGifDecoder.getFrame(i);
                        int t = mGifDecoder.getDelay(i);
                        mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(t);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (ntimes != 0)
                    {
                        repetitionCounter++;
                    }
                } while (mIsPlayingGif && (repetitionCounter <= ntimes));
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void stopRendering()
    {
        mIsPlayingGif = true;
    }
}
```

Несколько улучшил решение по ссылке, добавив классу `GifDecoderView` конструктор, принимающий вместо `InputStream` `URL` изображения, кое грузится `UIL`-ом, после загрузки достаётся из кэша, преобразуется в `FileInputStream` и далее отображается.

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь уже готовой библиотекой от ребят из Facebook - [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco). Умеет всё что вам нужно и много чего ещё, оптимизировано по самые помидоры. В общем готовая конфетка и не нужно никаких вышеописанных костылей.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробую в бою - отпишусь)